# 2D plot in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mayavi

I have 3 sets of data x,y,z where z represents the scan steps and z=50. Corresponding to z I have a each values of x and y. I want to plot a line or contour plot at 5th, 10th and 20th scan steps. Is it possible and which function should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand how your data is organized, but Matplotlib is the easiest way to pop up a contour plot: see this for example:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_label_demo.html
If you remove the last past of that URL, you can browse the entire gallery for more examples, some of which may be closer to what you are try to do.

A more involved and more powerful alternative would be Chaco. You can refer to this example:
http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/annotated_examples.html#contour-plot-py

Mayavi is for 3D plotting which doesn't seem to be what you are trying to do. If you are curious, checkout:
http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/

Hope this helps.